# Android unbindService

Tags: android, android-intent

Hello I have a little chat application, which bind to my service who creates a tcp/ip connection with my server.
I use aidl btw.

My problem is that I don't know to handle screen orientation especially on destroy method.

I would like that my service to be online all the time and I don't want to stop it when application destroys.

For now I have on "onDestroy" method unbindService(conn) to resolve the "leaked connection problem".

After activity is destroyed when is recreated it freeze.
Thank you, and here are some code snippets.

```
serviceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ChatService.class);
    boolean result = bindService(serviceIntent, conn,Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ChatService.class));
    Log.d(TAG, "Service binded");

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    Log.d(TAG, "ON DESTROY");
    unbindService(conn);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Service does not have UIs, therefore you may say that this does not depends on your service, but your activity. Return `START_STICKY` in `onStartCommand()` which tells you that it has to be running even when you unbind from it, basically you can bind/unbind any time to the persistent (not persistent until android OS decides to kill it) running service.

In your activity override `onConfigurationChange()` method and do nothing in it, then in your manifest use `android:configChanges="orientation"`.

Answer (score 0):

look into a `Service` and `startForeground()` ([link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29)). If you can let your `Service` die but get restarted, look into `onStartCommand()` and `START_STICKY`.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to happen every time, like you are experiencing. Having a bindedService actually tries to keep that Activity in memory longer than the other ones. I would suggest NOT unbinding from the service in onDestory. I would unBind your Service on command, like a log out button rather than on a lifecycle event.

So when your screen rotates you won't unBind it'll just rebind with the already running service. If your user kills Activity then the Service should get cleaned up at some point because the system should see that a bound Service is running without something attached and then it'll get cleaned up by the system.

Comment: Hello, thanks for response. I I remove unbind from onDestroy then i get "Activity has leaked ServiceConnection that was originally bound here”" and crash my application.